# Google OAuth2 client secret in plugin

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

i will develope a wordpress plugin to access google analytics and visualize the data in a widget. So i checked some existing wordpress plugins, like the famous known "Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)" - https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/. I was looking for a way how the user authorizes and get refresh and access token to access ga data in behalf of the user (who installed the plugin). And there i found that this plugin (and all other google analytics wodpress plugins) publish there secret. Because in a plugin (which the user downloads) it is impossible (i think) to hide the client secret, because the user of course see's the source code.

As the google documententation describes (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer): Important: Do not store the client_secrets.json file in a publicly-accessible location. In addition, if you share the source code to your application—for example, on GitHub—store the client_secrets.json file outside of your source tree to avoid inadvertently sharing your client credentials.

So in this case i think the authentication of the request is lost. If i get or guess a refresh token of any other website that uses the plugin, i will be able to exchange refresh token with access token (because i know the client id and secret) and access the ga data. I already tested that.

So i am looking for a more secure way to access the ga data in my plugin without letting everybody know my secret. Are there any solutions or hints? I thought about sending every request through my server, so nobody know's my secret, but this is also not the solution of the problem. When exchanging the authorization code and receiving the refresh token maybe i have to exchange something like a key pair that will be used to encrypt every following request? Every following request will be to get a new access code for a refresh token.

Of course every user can create his own client id and secret. But this is now very user friendly.

Maybe is it possible to create a new api project and oauth authentication via api (what you normaly do via the google api console)?

Thanks for your help and hints,
Harald

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS (or otherwise use PKCE) ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes i think PKCE will be the solution.